# Openlayers which format best for serving lat lon markers from webservice?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-service

I have a webservice which get GPS data (lat/lon) from android phone every 30 sec.
The webservice (currently) write the data to local log file (any format I decide).
which format/way will be best to read and refresh the layer every X seconds to show the location of the phone on OpenLayers OSM layer ?

Comment: I think the most "digestible" format is GeoJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for that a simple `JSON` with the lat/lon can do the work. Also it's something **light**,  so it won't consume a lot of **bandwidth** from the phone.

If you want something more complete you can go to [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON), that also would work.